# Questions about equivalence relations

Tags: relations

Assume $S$ and $R$ are two relations from the set $A$ to the set $B$, then $R∪S$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$. prove:

$Dom(R∪S)=Dom(R) ∪ Dom(S)$

$Im(R∪S)=Im(R) ∪ Im(S)$

for every $X⊆A$,$(R∪S)(X)=(R)(X) ∪ (S)(X)$

I tried using definition but I could not reach the desired result, any help or a little hint appreciated.

Comment: What do you think the domain is fo (1) $R$, (2) $S$, (3) $R\cup S$?

Comment: Domain for $R$ and $S$ is defined by $\left\{a∈A:\left(a,b\right)∈A\ for\ some\ b∈B\right\}$

Comment: So what is your difficulty with dom$(R\cup S)=$dom$(R)\cup$ dom$(S)$?

Comment: I just cannot prove that

Comment: Suppose $a\in\text{dom}(R\cup S)$. Then for some $b$ we have $(a,b)\in R\cup S$. So either $(a,b)\in R$ or $(a,b)\in S$ (or both). If $(a,b)\in R$, then $a\in\text{dom}(R)$; if $(a,b)\in S$, then $a\in\text{dom}(S)$. So dom$(R\cup S)\subseteq\text{dom}(A)\cup\text{dom}(B)$. Similarly, prove $\supseteq$.

Comment: What does this have to do with equivalence relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavy sketch for the first one, the rest is left for you.
$$\operatorname{Dom}(R\cup S)=\operatorname{Dom}(R)\cup\operatorname{Dom}(S).$$
Since these are sets, use a standard set-equality proof:

Let $a\in \operatorname{Dom}(R\cup S)$.  Then, there is some $b$ such that $(a,b)\in R\cup S$.  By the definition of union, $(a,b)\in R$ or $(a,b)\in S$.  Therefore, $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(R)$ or $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(S)$ by cases.

Let $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(R)\cup\operatorname{Dom}(S)$.  Then $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(R)$ or $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(S)$.  Wlog, we'll consider the first case.  Then there is some $b$ such that $(a,b)\in R$.  Since $R\subseteq R\cup S$, $(a,b)\in R\cup S$.  Hence $a\in \operatorname{Dom}(R\cup S)$.

Comment: very nice,do you have any idea for the third one?

Comment: @user715522 Yes, the second and third proofs are nearly identical.  There’s just a slight difference in where your elements are.